# How I can detect the shape inside of the jpanel and use it with another button

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

The class

```
 class MyComponent extends JComponent {
       public void paint(Graphics g) {

               g.fillRect(30, 30, 100, 100);

       }

    }
```

Jbutton is performed action on this

```
jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         jPanel4.add(new MyComponent());
         addComponent(new MyComponent());
      }
    });
 jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         jPanel4.add(new MyComponent1());
         addComponent(new MyComponent1());
      }
    });
```

I have some other Jbutton action as well . Now I want to detect the shape when it is in the panel. Then I want to perform some action on the panel current shape.

```
jButton5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==jButton1)
        {
            jPanel4.removeAll();
            jPanel4.updateUI();
            jPanel4.add(new MyComponent11());
             addComponent(new MyComponent11());
        }


      }
    });
```

But This code is not detecting the shape. Any solution for this please

Comment: `.. extends JComponent { public void paint(Graphics g) { ..` **should** be `.. extends JComponent { public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ..`

Comment: Don't use the updateUI() method, since you have NOT changed the UI. If you add/remove components on a visible GUI then use revalidate() and repaint().

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a general implementation of this using `Area`, which you can [find here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/). Specifically, the main method in AreaManager is informative as to how it all works together.

If you're just looking to detect mouse clicks in the bounds (30,30,100,100) you can implement that more easily in a regular `MouseListener / Adapter`. But it sounds like you're interested in the full solution, or?

Comment: Not, really, i just asking how jButton5 can detect the rectangle shape which will be draw in jpanel